# Phonegap, jQuery Mobile, Android, not fixed toolbar anymore after a text input

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile, footer, textinput

I have a problem as regards the combination of jQuery mobile, phonegap and android regarding the toolbars. To be more precise I would like both my header and footer to remain stable (data-position="fixed") after my input on a text area.

I also include the attribute data-tap-toggle="false" on both header and footer, but after I write something on the text area and return on the page the footer and the header are not "fixed" anymore, and I have to touch the screen again in order to be visible and fixed again.

Any advice?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution (works for me perfectly) is:

https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview

It is a combination of jquery mobile with iscroll.
Basically, it does all the nasty work joining the 2 mentioned libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem on iOS. After several hours, and trying several different things, I went for [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4). If there was any answer other than this, I would happy to hear.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Android 4.0.3 . I had a list with a search box. As soon as I tap the search box for input, the header and footer lost their fixed position. I got a very simple fix work for me.

```
    $('input[data-type=search]').live("focus", function() {
        $("[data-role=header]").css('position','fixed');
        $("[data-role=footer]").css('position','fixed');
    });
```

Hope it works !